# Accessing WiFi from a "Live" Linux DVD

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, dvd, arch-linux

I am stuck with a WINDOWS 8.1 machine -- I don't own it, so I cannot install Linux, either instead of Win or dual-boot.  I would like to run within a Linux system; so I have several "Live" DVD's.  With a bit of manual intervention I can boot the DVD.

BUT!  No matter what system I try -- so far ArchLinux, Ubuntu, and K-Ubuntu -- I cannot convince the NetworkManager to find the WiFi network, so I have no networking and can't do much of anything interesting.  ArchLinux.org has a [good instruction,](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_guide#Wireless_2) but it doesn't work for me.

Nothing seems to work!  But Windows has no trouble at all detecting and connecting me to the network.

TIA

Comment: what's your wifi card? Which versions of ubuntu? What sort of windows machine?

Comment: @Journeyman Geek:   'Puter: Dell "ACPI x64-based PC;" Intel Core i3    Net card:  Dell Wireless 1704 -- 802.11b/g/h (2.4 GHz) @ PCI 7:0:0   KUbuntu 15.11Alpha, Ubuntu and XUbuntu 15.04

Comment: these things ought to be in your question

Answer (score 0):

This may become a multistep problem depending on what the issue is, since you've specified your wireless card have you tried googling around for "Dell wireless 1704 arch linux"? the first link that comes up is [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=145884&p=3) seems to have a solution if you're lacking the driver.

Could you possibly post some error logs or something? When your machine is booting into Arch Linux and you see errors those will help us diagnose what's going on. Try opening terminal on the machine and look at the output of `systemctl --failed` if that does come up with an issue try `systemctl status <enter failed service here>`. Get those error messages and go back to Google.